# How can I set variables from a class of ArrayLists to the Main class?

Tags: java, class

I have already created an object and tried to set some variables but I cannot find the type of the variables that should I create in order to do not have any problem.

The part of the main class:

```
                Menu menu = new Menu();
                scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Give a code.");
                String code =  scanner.nextLine();
                menu.setCode(code);
                System.out.println("Give a main dish");
                String MainDish = scanner.nextLine();
                menu.setMainDishes(MainDish);
                System.out.println("Give a drink.");
                String Drink = scanner.nextLine();
                menu.setDrinks(Drink);
                System.out.println("Give a sweet.");
                String Sweet = scanner.nextLine();
                menu.setSweets(Sweet);
```

And the Menu class:

```
  public class Menu {
  ArrayList<String> MainDishes = new ArrayList<>();
  ArrayList<String> Drinks = new ArrayList<>();
  ArrayList<String> Sweets = new ArrayList<>();
  private String code;

  public ArrayList<String> getMainDishes() {
      return MainDishes;
  }

  public void setMainDishes(ArrayList<String> mainDishes) {
      MainDishes = mainDishes;
  }

  public ArrayList<String> getDrinks() {
    return Drinks;
  }

  public void setDrinks(ArrayList<String> drinks) {
      Drinks = drinks;
  }

  public ArrayList<String> getSweets() {
      return Sweets;
  }

  public void setSweets(ArrayList<String> sweets) {
      Sweets = sweets;
  }

  public String getCode() {
      return code;
  }

  public void setCode(String code) {
      this.code = code;
  }
```

Compliler give an error because of the String variables that I created.

Comment: Please post the error you are getting.

Comment: Your objects are Arraylists of Strings, not strings so you cannot use their setters with a string as parameter. To set the lists from the user input you have to add each time the input to your object's arraylist member variables. 


`String mainDish = scanner.nextLine();
 menu.getMainDishes().add(mainDish);`

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable and method names are always written in camelCase, so they start with lowercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your menu class contains ArrayList variables and you try to assign a String to them. Instead of:

```
menu.setMainDishes(MainDish);
```

Try:

```
menu.getMainDishes().add(MainDish);
```

Also, common convention in Java is to start variables with lowercase, eg `mainDish`.

Comment: I appreciate your answer! Is there any link to understand in-depth how this works? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Mike, glad I could help. This is pretty basic getter and setter logic, I've fould following tutorial online which might provide a lot of in-depth information on how to deal with these concepts, maybe it can be of use to you:  https://www.codejava.net/coding/java-getter-and-setter-tutorial-from-basics-to-best-practices

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a `string` when the methods are expecting an `ArrayList` of strings. If you want to do it the way you currently are, then create an `ArrayList`, put the user input into it, then pass that `ArrayList` to the methods that call for it.